# Java Properties and lambda collect

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a method that convert Properties into hashmap in this way (i know it's wrong)

```
Map<String, String> mapProp = new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream( path ));     

prop.forEach( (key, value) -> {mapProp.put( (String)key, (String)value );} );

return mapProp;
```

My idea is that mapping in a way like this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream( path ));

Map<String, String> mapProp = prop.entrySet().stream().collect( /*I don't know*/ );

return mapProp;
```

How write a lambda expression for do that?

Thanks all in advance

Andrea.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Collectors.toMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream( path ));

Map<String, String> mapProp = prop.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        e -> (String) e.getKey(),
        e -> (String) e.getValue()
    ));
```

Comment: So easy... I had tried in this way: Collectors.toMap( e -> (String) e.getKey(),  (String) e.getValue()) but ofcourse not work... Very very thanks, I have last question, have you a guide for lambda expression?

Comment: @AndreaCatania I started with javadoc and tutorials from Oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html

This article was also very helpful:
http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/

Answer (score 6):

Not actually an answer but may be useful to know for others passing by.

Since `Properties` extends `Hashtable<Object,Object>` which implements `Map<K,V>` you should not need to do anything other than:

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap(p);
```

Not quite sure why no warnings are offered for this code as it implies a cast from `Map<Object,Object>` to `Map<String,String>` is acceptable but I suspect that is a separate question.

Comment: what is the efficient way between constructor or lambda?

Comment: @AndreaCatania - I'd say let the system do it if you can, you should never optimise until you have proved that optimisation is necessary, so use the constructor.

Comment: You wrote `new HashMap(p)` (raw type), escaping generic type analysis; this is why your code only produces a warning and not an error, at least in Eclipse: "The expression of type `HashMap` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Map<String,String>`"

Comment: so the best solution is to use HashMap( p )?

Answer (score 1):

for those who want to use forEach

```
HashMap<String, String> propMap = new HashMap<>();
prop.forEach((key, value)-> {
   propMap.put( (String)key, (String)value);
});
```